# In AngularJS is there such a thing as a finally that runs after $http?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My code looks like this:

```
  $scope.login = function (userName, password, rememberMe) {
        authentication.authenticating = true;
        var config = {
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/api/Account/Login',
            data: { 'userName': userName, 'password': password, 'rememberMe': rememberMe }

        };
        $http(config)
            .success(function (data) {
                authentication.authenticating = false;
                authentication.isAuthenticated = true;
                $scope.template = $scope.templates[1];
                $scope.userName = userName;
            })
            .error(function (data) {
                $scope.loginError = "Invalid username/password combination";
                authentication.authenticating = false;
            });
    };
```

Is there a way I can move the authentication.authenticating = false; into some code block that will always execute after an error or success ?

Comment: yes there is `.finally(callback)` method on every promise - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q ...so you can do `$http.success(...).error(...).finally(...)`

Comment: @doodeec - Can you add this as an answer. Thanks

Comment: Correct, here's the checkin for that:

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/f078762d48d0d5d9796dcdf2cb0241198677582c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, since `$http` returns a promise, you can call `.finally(callback)` method as described in **$q** documentation [https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24q)

So you can use it in your case like this

```
$scope.login = function (userName, password, rememberMe) {
    authentication.authenticating = true;
    var config = {...};

    $http(config)
        .success(function (data) {
            authentication.isAuthenticated = true;
            $scope.template = $scope.templates[1];
            $scope.userName = userName;
        })
        .error(function (data) {
            $scope.loginError = "Invalid username/password combination";
        })
        .finally(function() {
            authentication.authenticating = false;
        });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try promise ($q)

Use $q.defered to take an object and after you can use resolve or reject in success or error http method

Sorry for short answer, i am on mobile.

Answer (score -1):

You can move that code into another method, like this, but you'd still have to call it manually from your success or failure functions:

```
  var setAuthenticating = function(){
                authentication.authenticating = false;
  }
  $scope.login = function (userName, password, rememberMe) {
        authentication.authenticating = true;
        var config = {
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/api/Account/Login',
            data: { 'userName': userName, 'password': password, 'rememberMe': rememberMe }

        };
        $http(config)
            .success(function (data) {
                setAuthenticating();
                authentication.isAuthenticated = true;
                $scope.template = $scope.templates[1];
                $scope.userName = userName;
            })
            .error(function (data) {
                $scope.loginError = "Invalid username/password combination";
                setAuthenticating();
            });
    };
```